# JqGrid filters afterSearch - which filter was used

Tags: search, jqgrid, filter

Is there a way to tell which filter was just invoked inside this event?

If so, please supply code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not here to do your work for you.  We will not write your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs it, here is the solution:

inside the afterToolbarSearch, you can do the following to grab the current filters. There will be an object containing objects with `field` and `data` properties.

`getGridParam("postData").filters` will return a string so you'd have to parse it to turn it into an object first and then refer to it as such.

```
params = $("#myGrid").getGridParam("postData").filters;
 var paramsObj = JSON.parse(params);
```